# Twitter бот на C#

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter, бот

Пишу твиттер-бот для консоли. В консоль должна вывестись моя лента. Использую библиотеку `TweetSharp`.

Cуть проблемы:

1. Зарегистрировал приложение в **Twitter**, вчера нормально авторизовывалось, а сегодня пишет "что нет доступа к приложению". Я так понимаю срок ключей истек и надо автоматически как-то запросить новые `SecretKey` и `ConsumerKey`?; Авторизация происходит по протоколу [OAuth2.0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0).
2. Не работает метод с выводом твит-ленты в консоль. Можете предложить работающий метод или указать на ошибку?
3. Посоветуйте где достать документацию на **[TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp)**, на *GitHub* очень мало информации.

Собственно, **код**:

```
using System;
using TweetSharp;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace twit_bot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Передаем свои учетные данные сервису (SecretKey, KonsumerKey)
            TwitterService service = new TwitterService("**********************", "***************************");

            // Шаг 1 - получаем маркер запроса протокола OAuth
            OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();

            // Шаг 2 - перенаправление по URL авторизации OAuth
            Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
            Process.Start(uri.ToString());

            // Step 3 - меняем маркер доступа на маркер
            string verifier = "12345"; // <-- Вводится пользователем
            OAuthAccessToken access = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);     

            //Читаем ленту
            TwitterService myTwitterService = new TwitterService();           
          var options = new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions { ScreenName = "sinecuraweb" };
            foreach (var tweet in myTwitterService.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(options))
                Console.WriteLine(tweet.Text);
        }
    }
}
```